# Implement template type constructors only if underlying type has those constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

Is there a way to encapsulate a type in a template class (akin to something like `std::optional`) that has all the necessary special constructors and assignment operators (i.e. copy ctor/assignment, move ctor/assignment) but only "enables" them if the underlying type has those functions? The functions in `type_traits` like `std::is_copy_constructible` look like they might help but I'm not sure how to use them to achieve this goal. For reference, the type I'm trying to implement is similar to `std::optional` but instead of the alternate value being simply "none" I want to use a custom error type. E.g.

```
template <typename T>
class ErrorOr {
 public:
  enum class Error {
    FATAL,
    WARNING,
    NONE,
  };

  ErrorOr(T val) : val(val), error(Error::NONE) {}
  ErrorOr(Error error) : error(error) {}

  // TODO: Implement copy/move ctors/assignment operators that only
  // exist if they do for the underlying T

  T get() { val; }

 private:
  T val;
  Error error;
};
```

This is a very bare-bones/minimal implementation that doesn't have a lot of the necessary features but hopefully illustrates the point I'm trying to make.

Is this possible in C++11?

Comment: Yes, optional works this way.

Comment: You're lacking a `return` inside the `get` member function. Also note that `ErrorOr` already assumes that T is copiable, since it copies a T value inside its `ErrorOr(T val)` constructor.

Comment: The simple way would be to implement them (even if `T` doesn't support it). You would get compile error when unsupported method would be used (and only if it is used). SFINAE/static_assert might have better error message. SFINAE would allow to use them in SFINAE context (but at worst, user can do it with `T`).

Comment: With this snippet, the implicitly-declared special members will do the right thing. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, do nothing. `ErrorOr<T>` having a member of type `T` will default all the special member functions to do the Right Thing. If `T` isn't copyable, `ErrorOr<T>` won't be either.

---

However, this also isn't really an optional type since you *always* have a `T`. If you eventually move to an implementation which conditionally has a `T`, 
one way to do this would be to inherit from an empty type that either enables or disables the special members as appropriate.

A simplified version would be:

```
template <bool allowCopies>
struct copy_enabler {
    copy_enabler() = default;
    copy_enabler(copy_enabler const& ) = default;
    copy_enabler& operator=(copy_enabler const& ) = default;
};

template <>
struct copy_enabler<false> {
    copy_enabler() = default;
    copy_enabler(copy_enabler const& ) = delete;
    copy_enabler& operator=(copy_enabler const& ) = delete;
};
```

Then you can simply:

```
template <typename T>
class ErrorOr : private copy_enabler</* is T copyable */> { ... };
```

In practice, you will want to do this for all the special member functions, and also add a tag type so that if you use this trick for multiple different class templates, they don't end up sharing a common base.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, class `X` has a copy constructor defined only if its template argument is of a class type and is copy-constructible (which means that it should have copy constructor):

```
template <typename T>
class X {
  static constexpr bool has_copy_constructor
    = std::is_class<T>::value && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value;
  struct dummy_type { };
public:
  X() = default;
  X(typename std::conditional<has_copy_constructor,
    const X &, const dummy_type &>::type) { std::cerr << "copy ctor\n"; }
  X(typename std::conditional<has_copy_constructor,
    const dummy_type &, const X &>::type) = delete;
};

int main() {
  X<std::string> x1;
  X<std::string> x2(x1); // OK

  X<int> x3;
  X<int> x4(x3); // ERROR
}
```

Not that I like this solution, but it kind of works.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, use std::enable_if (std::enable_if_t in newer c++ versions, not sure if that was added in c++11).

```
template<typename T>
struct my_type
    : T
{
    my_type(T && val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_move_constructible<T>::value>::type * = nullptr)
        : T(std::move(val))
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: C++11 has `enable_if<...>::type` and C++14 has the equivalent `enable_if_t<...>`

Comment: This will not work according to OP's needs. For instance, `int` is _move constructibe_, but has no move constructor.

Comment: If `my_type` inherits from `T`, then you're already inheriting whether or not the special members are valid. `enable_if` doesn't do anything for you.

Comment: @DanielLangr Well, the bigger problem is that you can't inherit from `int`.

Comment: Using `std::move` doesn't seem to make sense here since `val` is already an rvalue reference.

Comment: @Codoscope Yes, but `val` is an lvalue, so you have to `move` it.